Should I mention I was laid off when interviewers ask me to introduce myself?
I was recently laid off as a software engineer and have some interviews lined up. During interviews, the interviewer would usually introduce themselves first and ask you to introduce yourself as well (e.g. "Now it's your turn to tell me a bit about yourself"). Should I mention that I was laid off in that interview intro phase? Thank you!!!

Being laid off is not something "about yourself", so I agree with current answers

How do I just say "no" and keep the "comments must be 15 characters long" rule?

While it may feel like a life defining moment right now, it isn't.  It has happen to many awesome people and frequently it turns into a blessing.  Your goal should be to tell the interviewer the great things about yourself, of which there are many.

@PeteB. Thank you!!!

Consider this imaginary interaction:

Interviewer: "So tell us something about yourself!"
@Kay: "Well my name's Kay, and I was laid off..."

This script highlighting your recent redundancy as your main personal feature, is not really how you want to open the conversation, is it?
There's no need to withhold the fact of redundancy if you're asked why your previous job came to an end, or why you're looking for another. Employers lay off all the time nowadays.
And recruiting employers are usually looking to recruit recently unemployed workers desperate for another job, not to poach a perfectly satisfied employee from a competitor.
They're not typically looking for a redundancy to be confessed, or justified in any deep way. There's almost always a point in an interview when they ask why you're in the market and why you've left a previous job, and it's usually enough to state that there's unfortunately been a round of redundancies.
There is often a weak correspondence between what workers are told about the reason for redundancy, and the actual reason. Arbitrary selection may be trumped up as mildly poor performance, to avoid the remaining workers feeling upset by the truth of completely arbitrary execution. Poor performance may be dressed as arbitrary selection. And sometimes the employer just won't lie - but you won't actually know when you've been told the truth.
For these reasons, from an interviewer's perspective, probing the victim of a redundancy
about the circumstances (to try and get a greater indication of their quality as a candidate) is typically pointless.

No. Getting laid off is never in your favor, so there is no reason to mention it proactively.
This being said, it's almost guaranteed to come up, so you should be prepared to talk about it intelligently and clearly, which includes the "why". Put a good spin on it (if you can) but don't lie and don't sugarcoat: honesty is typically the best option.
During your introduction you should focus on all your positive things: what are you good at, what do you enjoy doing, what have you achieved that's relevant to the current gig, why do you think this is a good fit for both parties. It's a good idea to carefully write this out, edit it, make it flow well and concise (it needs to be short) and than practice it until you can deliver it well. End with something like "I'm really excited about this opportunity and I'm looking forward exploring this with you".

Thanks a lot!!!

"practice it until you can deliver it well" – just make sure you don't sound like a robot, rattling off memorized text.

@JörgWMittag. That's what "delivering it well" means. Flows naturally without sounding forced or excessive stumbling. If you can't do that the robot is still better than "well, uhm, that's a good question, let me think about it" At the least it demonstrates some amount of preparation.

it's sometimes better to head it off: if your last employer just had big layoffs (as many IT companies have had last year) then it'll be clear to everyone why you are looking for a new job. If 10.000 people got fired then it's not necessarily a bad mark towards you and some levity can show self-awareness. But don't start the conversation with it either.

No. It doesn't add value.
Don't lie if asked, but "I am looking for something that is a better fit", or in your own words a similar answer.
You are selling yourself and your skills.
You don't need to bring up some other company's negative business situation as if it was your responsibility. It has nothing to do with your skills and value to the new company.


During interviews, the interviewer would usually introduce themselves
first and ask you to introduce yourself as well (e.g. "Now it's your
turn to tell me a bit about yourself"). Should I mention that I was
laid off in that interview intro phase?

During the introduction. No with a couple of caveats.

You are applying for a position within your current company. The reason why they are considering you is because they have an immediate need to be filled now, and you have a rapidly approaching deadline.  I worked for a company that had a list of people that have been notified their job is disappearing so that managers can reach out to them. I even found one position this way.

The person doing the interview already knows this. This could be somebody you worked with in the past, and they have suggested you apply for the opening. They already know your situation, they already believe you have good qualities, and you probably qualify for the position.


So when do you let them know?

When they ask where are you working now. Sometimes there is a delay between application and the interview. I once had a delay of almost a year between when I applied, and when they asked if I could interview. If the resume said 2021 to present, but now that isn't true you shouldn't lie about it.

When it is advantageous for you. At some point your immediate availability is a strength for you. It can be a weakness if they think your lack of income means they can offer you less. But in other cases if they need to fill the position next week, your availability is a point in your favor. I once negotiated a signing bonus because I still had a job, but the deadline was closing and my current company could save money if  left sooner. The new company earned a bonus from their customer if the position was filled by the end of the month. I was able to start the next Monday, just beating the deadline by a few days.


Be prepared to answer this question in a couple of different scenarios. You may have to answer it multiple times, if there are multiple rounds of interviews.
